# Return type of abs is complex?

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

Does std::abs return a complex value? That is, a real value represented as a complex number with zero imaginary part. I get this error

`g++ -march=native "utilities.cpp" -fpic -g -Wall -c -std=c++11 -I"/home/torbjorr/deployed" -o "__wand_targets_dbg/utilities.o"`

> `In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
>                    from /home/torbjorr/deployed/herbs/memory/memory.h:14,
>                    from /home/torbjorr/deployed/vector/matrixstorage.h:10,
>                    from frame_in.h:9,
>                    from utilities.cpp:6:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_OIter std::transform(_IIter, _IIter, _OIter, _UnaryOperation) [with _IIter = std::complex<float>*; _OIter = float*; _UnaryOperation = std::complex<float> (*)(const std::complex<std::complex<float> >&)]':
>   utilities.cpp:89:34:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4926:12: error: cannot convert 'std::complex<float>' to 'float' in assignment
>     *__result = __unary_op(*__first);`

When called like this:

```
std::transform(spectrum.begin(),spectrum.end(),temp.begin()
    ,std::abs<std::complex<float> >);
```

From cppreference.com:

```
template< class T > T abs( const complex<T>& z );
```

So in this case, I expect a float back.

Comment: [no, it doesn't](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/abs).

Comment: `std::abs<std::complex<float>>`, expects a `std::complex<std::complex<float>>` as an argument, and yes, the return type would be a `std::complex<float>`. Perhaps you meant to use `std::abs<float>`, the argument for which would be `std::complex<float>`.

Comment: With the given signature, `std::abs<std::complex<float> >` will be `std::complex<float> abs(const std::complex<std::complex<float>>&z)`... I think you mean `std::abs<float>`

Comment: Both Benjamin and Jarod gave the solution.

Comment: Strangely, `std::abs<std::complex<float> >` actually instantiated for me. I'm not sure what it does. I think it instantiates only with parameter type `complex< complex<float> >` , which is convertable from `complex<float>` of course. Inside, it's doing several complex muls, a complex divide, and a complex square root. Maybe it's giving the main branch of `sqrt(z*z)`. In any case `complex<T>` is not usable when T is not float, double, or long double, so it's only a curiosity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::transform(spectrum.begin(),spectrum.end(),temp.begin()
    ,std::abs<std::complex<float> >);
```

Note here you are trying to use `std::abs<std::complex<float>>`. In that case, the template argument `T` is `std::complex<float>`. If you replace `T` in the signature of `std::abs`, you get this:

```
std::complex<float> abs( const std::complex<std::complex<float>>& z );
```

I believe the function you intended to use was `std::abs<float>`, which would result in a signature like this:

```
float abs(const std::complex<float>& z);
```

Comment: And `std::abs<float>` is still overloaded, but in the OP's usage, should resolve to the complex magnitude, as you say, due to the types of the other parameters to `std::transform`

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says the type of expressions

`spectrum.begin()` and `spectrum.end()`is `std::complex<float>*`

while the type of expression `temp.begin()` is `float*`

You are trying to apply function

```
template< class T > T abs( const complex<T>& z );
```

to an object of type float but there is no implicit conversion from type `complex<float` to type `float.`.

**error: cannot convert 'std::complex' to 'float' in assignment
    *__result = __unary_op(*__first);**

Answer (score -2):

The absolute value of any number (real or complex) is defined as the length of the vector from the origin to its point on the Argand plane.

This is a real number.

Comment: -1? If I'm incorrect here I'm going to become a farmer or a poet.

Comment: Correct but not helpful for this question. The comments on the question give useful explanations.

Comment: I had wanted to reassure the OP that the return value of `abs` **certainly is not** complex. `abs` has this curious definition that I think is worth pointing out explicitly.